# Why do I need to store the bump inside the PDA?

Tags: anchor

It seems like when I `init` a PDA in Anchor, I have to save the bump it creates within the PDA. Later, I use this stored bump when working with `mut` accounts.

Why do I have to save the bump? Can't it just be recalculated whenever needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storing the bump within the PDA is a good practice to help save that PDA calculation time.

For example, running `find_program_address` without the bump can cause your program's instruction to take a lot more CU usage.

Without bump:

```
// 12,136 CUs!
Pubkey::find_program_address(&[b"counter"], ctx.program_id);
```

With Bump:

```
// 1,651 CUs
Pubkey::create_program_address(&[b"counter", &[248_u8]], &program_id).unwrap();
```

You can see in the example above, we saved more than 10,000 CUs storing the bump and reusing it when looking up the PDA. This can be more CUs or potentially less depending on how high the lookup has to increase the bump to find a valid PDA.

Some more information can be found on [the optimization guide](https://solana.com/developers/guides/advanced/how-to-optimize-compute#program-derived-addresses).